# Trying to get SSH over USB to work (Raspberry pi Zero W)

Tags: usb, ssh, pi-zero, headless

I'm trying to connect to my Raspberry Pi Zero W using SSH over USB. I've seen other people do it, and I have tried multiple different tutorials over the last few days, but none of them worked. I've seen this question being asked and answered many times, but all answers i found seem to be outdated, because none of them worked.
I have connected my Pi to my computer (yes, I have used the correct USB plug) with a modified image of the latest version of raspbian stretch lite.
**What I modified:**
-Added an empty file called "ssh" to the root dir
-Added `dtoverlay=dwc2` to config.txt
-Added `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` to cmdline.txt (after `rootwait`)

Now, when i plugged the pi into my PC, It got recognized as a "Serial COM port".
It *should* be recognized as an RNDIS Gadget, according to the tutorials.
I then downloaded and installed the "Acer Inc. Other hardware - USB ethernet RNDIS gadget" driver from [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=USB%20RNDIS%20Gadget).
Now, when i plug in my pi, it shows up like this in the device manager:[image: Device Manager Screenshot]
But I still could not ping it / connect to it via PuTTY.
[image: ping raspberrypi.local]
Sorry for the german. It says "could not find host raspberrypi.local".

I then tried to find the IP address of the Pi in the new network, and i noticed it had none. My PC has an address (192.168.137.1) on the new network, just not the Pi.
Any Idea what I could do?

I still can't figure this out. I hope my progress so far will help others with the same problem, since all online resources seem to be outdated by around 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a linux system. For me the solution was to install "avahi-daemon". The underlying problem is the failing DNS for the USB-device (meaning: the name raspberrypi.local has to be resolved somehow)
I hope this can point in the right direcetion:

On **Windows**, it seems, that you have to install something called Bonjour service.

Relating to [this article](https://learn.adafruit.com/bonjour-zeroconf-networking-for-windows-and-linux/overview):

> Windows doesn’t have Zeroconf support out of the box, but a few popular applications slip it in for their own needs, including Skype, Apple’s iTunes and Adobe Photoshop CS3 or later. So you might not need to add anything at all!
>
> Otherwise, it’s most easily installed using Bonjour Print Services for Windows 2.0.2.
>
> ... -> https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_US

Comment: On the used Raspbian Stretch Lite **avahi** is installed by default. As the OP wrote, the RasPi does not have an ip address so name resolution will not help.

Comment: @ingo: "The Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon implements Apple's Zeroconf architecture (also known as "Rendezvous" or "Bonjour"). The daemon registers local IP addresses and static services using mDNS/DNS-SD" (
die.net
avahi-daemon(8)) "The Avahi daemon discovers network resources, allocates IP addresses without the DHCP server, makes the computer accessible by its local machine name by acting as a DNS server and facilitates sharing of files and printers" (https://ccm.net/faq/739-disabling-the-avahi-daemon)
So if avahi is installed, it could be stopped or disabled

Comment: Yes, you are right. You explained zeroconf and multicast DNS, but you don't explain why the RasPi does not have an ip address.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already have Bonjour installed (and recently manually reinstalled it, just in case), but this still doesn't work. however, when I install https://github.com/MaMe82/P4wnP1 and run install.sh, i can ssh into it using the IP it gave itself. Something in there made it work, but i still need to find out what did, because if i need to use the pi for anything else than P4wnP1, I have to solve this exact problem again.